# How to change the fontsize when writing to a text file

Tags: java, fonts, font-size

I am writing information to a text file, how do i I change the font size for Data that i am writing to the text file. also how do you set the data to be written in bold or underlined.

Comment: What format is your text file? Plain text (.txt) doesnt support such formatting. Maybe you are referring to html? or rtf? or... ?

Comment: A plain txt in notepad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the .txt format does not contain formatting such as font size, bond, italics, etc.

You probably want to use a `markup language` like `html`, or another file format, such as `rtf`, `pdf` or something else.

Here's some information on learning html: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)

And a java library for writing rtf: [srw library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/srw/)

And a java library for writing pdf: [pdfbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

Good luck.

Comment: I'd say fortunately, else the file format would be a lot less useful :)

Comment: Why pdfBox and not iText? I've always used iText

Comment: @jwenting you are of course correct, removed the word unfortunately :)

Comment: @Federico sure, iText, why not! I'm by no means an expert with pdf, so thanks for the nice suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Plaintext files do not have format and style options.

For this you would have to write the data in a different format. E.g. html if you want to view it in a browser later.
But the format you chose greatly depends upon how and by whom those data should be read.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are editing your text in a JTextArea you might do this:

```
this.textArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
//the code comments itself
```

if you want `bold` then write `Font.BOLD`

As someone already told you, unfortunately plain `.txt` files don't contain formatting. If you need to format the text, you should change format and try `HTML`.

Comment: See comments, he said he is writing to notepad.

Comment: My fault, I understood that he created its own notepad and he wanted to set the font while writing. Anyway it can helps posterity :)

Comment: Are you ironical? Ahah, if you're not, then you're welcome :P

Answer (score 0):

As all people say .txt files don't have format options.
I want to clarify something 
It's possible have a txt file with specific format.
The way to do it is with a specific viewer:
You can add style, text size with notepad
You can add underlines or line spacing with notepad++
depending on you txt viewer you can postformat.

Then a possible solution would be POSTFORMATING, it works, for example if you want to print your file, only change setting on your viewer and you could obtain the result that you are looking for.

I'm working in this way for printing my txt reports.